# Grails unit & integration tests file name conflict using Intellij IDE

Tags: unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea

I use Intellij(ultra version) IDE to develop Grails application.

If I have a controller named UserController and then use Intellij to create both unit and integration tests for this.

Intellij will create two files have same name but in different folder.

e.g /unit/xxx/yyy/UserControllerSpec
    /integration/xxx/yyy/UserControllerSpec

However, Intellij IDE has some error alert for file already exists. I know it is acceptable and I run the tests pass. Just the annoying error.

Anyone knows how to disable this Intellij annoying error?

Comment: I have also experienced this issue - I have submitted a ticket with Intellij support to resolve

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have two classes with the same name in the same package even if they're in different folders.  Rename one, e.g. `UserControllerIntegrationSpec` or `UserControllerUnitSpec`.

Comment: Actually I can have something like this. No complaint if I run the tests or the app. Just IDE complaint

Comment: Burt, the files names are given by the `grails Create*Test` command. Are you suggesting renaming them?

Comment: Not suggesting, stating explicitly :)